# JavaScript doesn't change iframe src (using Bootstrap frontend)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am using the following JavaScript (in the script tag in head) to modify an iframe's src when a link is clicked.

```
function switchView() {
    document.getElementById("project-view").src = 'projects/3dpool.html';
}
```

My iframe is written as

```
<iframe id="project-view" src="projects/fallingballs.html" onload="resizeIframe(this);" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The link that changes the iframe is:

```
<a href="" class="list-group-item" onclick="switchView();">3D Pool</a>
```

Adding a log statement like `document.getElementById("project-view").src` after the src change shows that the src has actually changed but no changes show up.

I have tried removing the unload tag from the iframe but it doesn't help.

Typing out the code in the switchView() function in the web console works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your link to look like the following:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onclick="switchView(); return false;">3D Pool</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 
I am testing on both Safari and Firefox. Also, typing the line of code on the console works but I can't do it by clicking the link

Comment: This works. The empty href was the issue. Don't need the return false there. Thanks!

Comment: the return false is so your page doesn't jump to the top of the browser window when you click the link.  feel free to remove if thats not a concern for you.  If your link is near the top you won't notice it, but later if your link moves down the page or you use this code again further down, the return false will save your butt... :-)